# how to refer to a user control's "strong" type

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have code like this which loads a control from an .ascx file, calls some methods of the control, then renders it:

```
Option Explicit Off

Sub renderMyControl(p As Page)
    Dim ctrl as Object = p.LoadControl("path/to/myControl.ascx")
    ' ... do stuff with ctrl ...
    ctrl.DoThing1()
    ' ...
    ctrl.RenderControl(New HtmlTextWriter(p.Response.Out))
End Sub
```

This code only works because `Explicit` is off.  I would like to use `CType` to convert the control to its "strong type" (and get rid of `Option Explicit Off`) but I don't know how to add a reference to the type.  How can I do this?

Comment: So you are asking how to find out what type `"path/to/myControl.ascx"` is? Are you not the author? System.Reflection springs to mind.

Comment: @Jodrell, I am the author ... I can't use reflection because I want the type to be known to the compiler, so it can check the method and property names of the user control and I can turn off Option Explicit... as it is, it's doing no checking at compile-time, just at run-time.

Comment: So, add a reference to assembly that contains the Web User Control called myControl, is that not possible? Is that project in the same solution? In VB they are listed under the project properties, not in the solution explorer but, you still get the option in the context menu of the project. Am I missing the point?

Comment: It doesn't have a an assembly or project... it's a "web site"

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET or C#? I think you got your samples mixed up a bit. :)

This will work - in VB.NET:

```
Sub renderMyControl(ByVal p As Page)
  Dim ctrl = CType(p.LoadControl("myControl.ascx"), myControl)
  ctrl.DoThing1()
  ctrl.RenderControl(New HtmlTextWriter(p.Response.Output))
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not asking how to use CType... I'm asking "how do I add a `reference` to the type".  Without any reference I will get a build error due to `myControl` being unrecognized

Comment: Does the myControl user control have a codebehind class? I created a test project and added a web user control named "myControl", and the above code just works. Maybe your myControl class is hidden in a namespace somewhere? Btw. your sample still has semicolons and C# style comments. :)

Comment: I fixed up the syntax (I'm showing the telltale signs of a dev who constantly switches languages :)  I will try it again once I get to work and let you know the error I'm getting

Comment: I get: `Type 'myControl' is not defined`... I tried making it `ASP.myControl` and it didn't help

Comment: Can you post the source of the control, both .ascx and .vb?